# Control top and bottom margins of an image?

Tags: spacing, graphics

Using `includegraphics` seems to set default margins that gives a nice spacing between text and image. But I'd like to layout the text as close as possible to the image.  How do I control the margins of an image?

Change from:

```
|     #TEXT######################### |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| #######################            |
|                                    | % <-- margin from image is a bit tall
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|           **IMAGE.JPG**            |
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|                                    | % <-- margin from image is a bit tall
|     #TEXT######################### |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| #################                  |
```

To:

```
|     #TEXT######################### |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| #######################            | % <-- as close as possible
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|           **IMAGE.JPG**            |
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|           *************            |
|     #TEXT######################### | % <-- as close as possible
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| ################################## |
| #################                  |
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, `\includegraphics` does not add any margins by itself. You seem to use it either inside a `figure` or `center` environment which both add margins.

The distance between floats like `figure` and `table` is defined by the lengths `\textfloatsep` and for `figure*` in `twocolumn` documents by `\dbltextfloatsep`.
You can set these to zero to remove all separation.

Should you use the `center` environment instead, replace it with `\centerline{\includegraphics[..]{..}}`.

You can also add and remove some vertical space before and after the `\includegraphics` using `\vspace{<length>}` where the length can be positive or negative.

Comment: Yes, I was using the `center` environment. Now using `centerline`, problem solved, thanks!

Comment: Sadly `\vspace` does not work with your `adjustbox` package. Any alternative?

Comment: @user134593: Did you tried `\par\vspace{<length>}\par` before the actual content? For `adjustbox` there is the `vspace` *key*. See the manual p. 14.

Comment: @MartinScharrer i used `\raisebox` instead =)

Comment: @user134593: Well `adjustbox` has keys for that too ;-)